# html template if statement

Tags: php, html, templates, if-statement

PHP code (functions.php)

```
$main = $db_sql->query_array("SELECT catid,titel,subcat,startorder FROM $cat_table WHERE catid='$subcat'");
$tpl->register('category_title',stripslashes($main['titel']));
$tpl->register('category_id',$main['catid']);
```

So I want to add an if statement where if `{category_id}` is not 0 then do the following code

```
<img src="{GRAFURL}/{category_id}.jpg" alt="{category_title}" width="50" height="50" border="0" align="middle" />&nbsp;{category_title}
```

what would be the correct syntax?

need more code still for the html file?

Comment: HTML as a markup language has no concept of if-else logic. Are you using a template language?

Comment: Are you using any sort of templating/server-side language to parse this? Right now this isn't valid HTML...

Comment: @wylie yeah i just added the actual php code that calls the info into the template file

Comment: yeah brain farts for the win lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML doesn't have dynamic features like if-statements. Think of HTML as a language to define a layout - **unchangeable using HTML itself**.

This should do the trick:

```
<?php

  if ( false === is_empty( $category_id )) {

    echo  "<img src='{$GRAFURL}/{$category_id}.jpg' alt='{$category_title}' 
            width='50' height='50' 
            border='0' align='middle' />&nbsp;{$category_title} ";

  }

?>
```

In case you need to add client-side dynamic features to your HTML-pages, have a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: Can you update your answer to reflect changes in the original question? i.e. yes, he's using PHP. This looks basically right though, you need to wrap the HTML in a PHP if statement.

Answer (score 2):

HTML has no such capability. You would need to generate your HTML using a programming language. Then the syntax would depend on which language you were using.

e.g. in [TT](http://template-toolkit.org/index.html):

```
[% IF category_id %]
<img src="[% GRAFURL %]/[% category_id %].jpg" 
     alt="{category_title}" width="50"
     height="50" border="0" align="middle"
     />&nbsp;[% category_title %]
[% END %]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript for generating it client side, PHP for server side. Javascript can change things on the page and provide dynamic content **after** the page is sent to the client; PHP can determine the content **before** sending it to the user (while it can edit it afterwords, it is much more convoluted).

For example, if you wanted to add it to a  tag with id "dynamic", you could use this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
var img_tag = document.createElement('img');
img_tag.src = "{GRAFURL}/{category_id}.jpg";
img_tag.alt = "{category_title}";
img_tag.width = 50;
img_tag.height = 50;
img_tag.border = 0;
img_tag.align = "middle";
document.getElementById("dynamic").appendChild(img_tag);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dynamic">
</div>
<body>
</html>
```

I thoroughly recommend learning jQuery, however, where you could do things easier and faster. Also, it is up to you to replace the values in braces with the correct values (either through PHP or javascript), I couldn't tell what you were doing.